# Points nearest and farthest from origin, Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

The plane $x + y + 2z = 30$  intersects the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ in an ellipse.

Find the points on the ellipse that are nearest to and farthest from the origin.

I know you have to find the gradient for $f$, but after that, I have no clue how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

let $d^2(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

you want $\nabla (d^2)$ to be in the plane of $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$. That is, for some $\lambda$ and $\mu$, you want 
$$\nabla(d^2)+\lambda\nabla f+\mu\nabla g=0.$$

Comment: So you get:<2x, 2y, 2z> + λ<1,1,2> + μ<2x, 2y, -1> = 0

Comment: Now what do I do?

Comment: Let's do a confidence check, that is, let's count unknowns, and pray that we have as many equations. Our unknowns are $x,y,z,\lambda,\mu$, five unknowns. We have the three equations you write in the comment above, plus $f=g=0$, two more, so that's five equations, so there's hope. Let's smash them together and pray.

Comment: a thought, four of the equations are linear, might apply some linear algebra to those, I would think that would organize the work some. if my intuition is wrong, let us know what goes wrong please.

Comment: I cannot figure it out. Any other hints/help you can give me?

Comment: oops, they're not linear, because the way $\lambda$ and $\mu$ show up.

Comment: I got x = 5/2 , -3 ; with x=y

Comment: It's not right.

Comment: i'm playing with it. so far i have one fact, $\mu\ne 0$ implies $x=y$. were you careful about considering all cases?

Comment: on the other hand, if $\mu=0$, i still get $x=y$. how do you know it is wrong?

Comment: There's a way for me to check the answers online.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.